# sql database in ef

Tags: sql, entity-framework

i use ef in wpf application
i want to avoid accessing to database structure and data after installing app on customers system.

i used sql compact edition but it is very slow than sql express,
then i used sql express instead of ce edition but it's .mdf file can attach to an instance sqlserver simply and access to its structure and data.
(in my app confidentiality of database and speed of responsiveness are very important)

please tell me your best solution:

Comment: why don't you go next option SQL server 2014/16 ?

Comment: i think, sql server 2014/16 are heavy and i need a light version,express in lighter than sql server and sql compact edition is lighter than express,but compact is slow

Comment: the problem is not on the db.it's on your `ef queries`.if you have any specific query to optimise, we can help to you.

Comment: i want to use sql as database for accounting software, Your idea is to use sql compact and optimize queries or another edition of sql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your security constrain,I think the best fit is `SQL CE`.But you're worrying about the performance of the app.That is not due to database provider.That is due to issues of EF queries on your app.So my suggestion is to optimise those queries. Firstly you have to identify the very slow one,then next one and so on.

You have to consider the below mentioned items when you do the optimisation.

> 1. Cold vs. Warm Query Execution
> 2. Caching in the Entity Framework
> 3. Autocompiled Queries
> 4. NoTracking Queries
> 5. Query Execution Options
> 6. Design time performance considerations
> 7. Loading Related Entities
> 8. Other Considerations
> 9. Investigating Performance

You can get huge knowledge about above topics using this article : [**Performance Considerations for Entity Framework**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853.aspx)